# Writing string to pipe

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I am trying to send a string to a pipe in unix. When I go through a line-by-line debugging process, the call mkfifo() creates the file in the same directory as the source code. However, when I reach the open() call, the debugger is no longer able to proceed. I'm not sure why it is unable to access the pipe file.

Here's the code in question:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
int fd;
char * myfifo = "myfifo";

/* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

/* write "Hi" to the FIFO */
fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
close(fd);

/* remove the FIFO */
unlink(myfifo);

return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Always check the returned value from open() and write() and mkfifo()   Such checking would have told the program what failed (in this case, probably the write(), however, after the first run of the program, any successive runs would have failed on the mkfifo() because the fifo already exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally a FIFO has to be open at both ends simultaneously before either side can proceed.  Since you didn't mention anything about a reader, the most likely answer is that you haven't got one, or you haven't set it up yet.  Once you do, the open will be allowed to proceed.

Comment: I do have a reader.c file created and compiled. How would I go about opening them simultaneously? so far I have compiled both the writer and reader into separate executables and have ran them. I will update my code to include reader.c

Comment: @Johnny Easiest solution: open two terminals, and run one in each?

Comment: @Johnny you just have to have both the reader and the writer running at the same time. For example, start your reader process, then in a different terminal, start your writer process.  Once both are running, they will be allowed to proceed.

Comment: Okay, that worked. I'm a complete noob with the command line but it did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[mkfifo(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) routes to [fifo(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo) which reads:

> The kernel maintains exactly one pipe object for each FIFO special file that is opened by at least one process.  The FIFO must be opened on both ends (reading and writing) before data can be passed. **Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.**

There is a solution for non-blocking **read**:

> A process can open a FIFO in nonblocking mode. In this case, opening for read only will succeed even if no-one has opened on the write side yet, **opening for write only will fail** with ENXIO (no such device or address) unless the other end has already been opened.

So you could fork another process for reading:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


long strlen(char * c){
    return c[0] == 0 ? 0 : 1 + strlen(++c);
}

int main()
{
    int fd;
    int fr;
    char buf[3];
    char * MESSAGE = "Hi\n";
    char * myfifo = "myfifo";

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);


    int msglen = strlen(MESSAGE);
    int child = fork();
    if (child == 0){
        /* read "Hi" from the FIFO (CHILD)*/
        fr = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fr, buf, msglen);
        write(1, buf, msglen);
        close(fr);

    } else {
        /* write "Hi" to the FIFO (PARENT)*/
        fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
        write(fd, MESSAGE, sizeof(char) * msglen);
        close(fd);

        /* remove the FIFO */
        wait(child);
        unlink(myfifo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I guess you have to open both ends before you write.

Answer (score 0):

here is an excerpt from the man page for mkfifo()  See my notes at the end

```
  mkfifo() makes a FIFO special file with name pathname.  mode
   specifies the FIFO's permissions.  It is modified by the process's
   umask in the usual way: the permissions of the created file are (mode
   & ~umask).

   A FIFO special file is similar to a pipe, except that it is created
   in a different way.  Instead of being an anonymous communications
   channel, a FIFO special file is entered into the filesystem by
   calling mkfifo().

   Once you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process
   can open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an ordinary
   file.  However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before
   you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening
   a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the
   same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.  See fifo(7) for nonblocking
   handling of FIFO special files.
```

Notes: There are two details of importance:

```
1) the 'mode' parameter is modified by the value of 'umask'
2) both ends of the fifo must be open at the same time
   before any I/O operations can be performed.
```